# Azure Build pipeline not able to retrieve latest source version

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops

I'm running into a strange problem whenever I start a particular build, and I can't get my head around it.

I just imported an existing VSTS-repository into my new GIT-Repository on Azure DevOps. My next step is to create a Build-pipeline which should lead to an artifact which I can deploy. For the company I work for I've done this many times, but I've never seen this error before.

The buildpipeline is setup, and as soon as I start a build it immediately fails with the following error;
[image]

Hopefully somebody can help out in resolving this.

**UPDATE - Added settings for retrieving sources**
[image]

Comment: Can you share your Build "Get Sources" settings?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I'll add a screenshot of those.

Comment: Does the repo have a `master` branch?

Comment: @DanielMann, yes. There is just one single branch at the moment, which is the master.

Comment: Okay, this is really embarassing, but after I pasted the additional screenshot I'd seen that I selected the wrong repo.. How stupid! Everything is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting the second screenshot and going through everything again properly, I saw that I didn't point the Build Pipeline to the proper GIT-Repository in Azure Devops. After updating this, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, a branch was referred in the pipeline which someone had "locked". Due to this, the pipeline was unable to find that branch and was failing with this error.